# How to get fixed number of subview from all subview of scrollview using fast enumeration in ios

Tags: ios, scrollview, subview, nsfastenumeration

How to select fix number of subview from all subview of scrollview using fast enumeration in ios?

Comment: Please provide details explanation - What you want to achieve, What you have done, What problem you faced, What you expected to do.

Comment: I have one scrollview that consist of ten dynamically generated buttons. I want to access only first 5 buttons from scrollview using fast enumeration. so please provide some solution to get only 5 buttons from the loop like "for(UIButton *btn in scrollview)".

Comment: please provide more detail varsha

Answer (score 0):

do as following:
1.give tags to your buttons when you are creating them.for example:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.tag = 1;
[button addTarget:self
       action:@selector(aMethod:)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[view addSubview:button];
```

2.do not understand why you want to use fast enumeration, you can simple get your buttons by:

```
UIButton *btn1 = (UIButton *)[self.yourScrollView viewWithTag:1];
UIButton *btn2 = (UIButton *)[self.yourScrollView viewWithTag:2];
UIButton *btn3 = (UIButton *)[self.yourScrollView viewWithTag:3];
UIButton *btn4 = (UIButton *)[self.yourScrollView viewWithTag:4];
UIButton *btn5 = (UIButton *)[self.yourScrollView viewWithTag:5];
```

2.if your requirement is to  using fast enumeration, take an NSMutableArray to hold your buttons:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
for (id btn in self.yourScrollView.subviews)
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        if (btn.tag > 0 || btn.tag<=5)
        {
            [arrayOfButtons addObject:btn];
        }
    }
}
```

hope it will help you.